# convert ascii / binary to decimal in assembly language

Tags: assembly, binary, x86, ascii

i wanted to convert a binary number to a decimal in assembly but i keep on getting zero

this is the number

```
aLength     db  "00000000000000000000000000010101", NULL
```

and i tried using this code to get each character and subbing by '0' multiplying by 2 and adding but it keeps saying that the answer is 0

```
mov rbx,aLength
mov dword[rsum],0
mov ecx,0
mov r10,32


lp: 
mov cl,byte[rbx]
sub cl,'0'
mov eax,dword[rsum]
mul dword[two]
add eax,ecx
mov dword[rsum],eax
add rbx,1
dec r10
cmp r10,0
jbe lp

mov r8d,dword[rsum]
mov byte[aLength],r8b
```

Comment: looks ok to me, except the `mul dword[two]` which is suspicious, unfortunately you didnt show us "two" ... for a multiply by 2, try `add eax, eax` (or a `shl`) instead

Comment: Looks like x86 assembly (pretty much every CPU family has its own assembly, can't generalize this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code loops only once, this is because you inverted the looping condition

```
cmp r10, 0
jbe lp
```

Should be

```
cmp r10, 0
ja lp
```

Since `r10` hold the remaining number of bits to convert.
Once you change that line your code works.

---

That said, it can be simplified and made more readable.
One nice trick to use when converting from binary to decimal is the use of the carry flag.

Shifting instruction put the output bit (the lsb for a left shift, the msb for a right shift) into the carry flag.
Using the `rcl`/`rcr` instruction we can grab that bit and shift it back into another register.

Since the ASCII value for *'1'* is 31h, which is odd, hence have bit 0 set, and the ASCII value for *'0'* is 30h, which is even, hence have bit 0 clear; by shifting the digit ASCII value right by 1 we set the carry flag according do the intended digit value: 0 for '0' and 1 for '1'.
Now we can use `rcl` to shift that bit into `eax`.

I also prefer using whole register when possible, and put white lines between functional separated pieces of code.
Finally I capitalize memory size specifiers like WORD, DWORD, BYTE (PTR where applicable) just to easily spot memory operations.
One more: I removed all the intermediary memory access.

```
xor eax, eax           ;Converted value (so far)
mov rbx, aLength       ;Pointer to ASCII digits
mov r10, 32            ;Bits left to convert

_convert:
  movzx ecx, BYTE [rbx] ;Grab a digit
  add rbx, 1            ;And increment the pointer

  shr ecx, 1            ;Set CF according to the digit value
  rcl eax, 1            ;Shift CF into EAX from right (Rotate left)

  sub r10, 1            ;Decrement count
ja _convert

;Store results
mov DWORD [rSum], eax
mov BYTE [aLength], al
```