# convert decimal to ASCII / binary in assembly

Tags: assembly, binary, decimal, ascii

I am trying to convert a given decimal number into a 32 character binary number but my code keeps giving me the wrong answer

Number i am trying to convert to binary

```
aLength     db  21
```

variables the i used

```
two         dq      2
tempString  resb    33
```

i tried to divide the aLength (21) by 2 32 times and stacking all the remainders but it is not working

here is my code

```
mov rax,0
mov eax,byte[aLength]
mov rcx,32

lp2:
mov rdx,0
div qword[two]
push rdx
loop lp2
mov rsi,tempString
mov rcx,2

lp3:
pop rax
add al,"0"
mov byte[rbx],al
inc rbx
loop lp3
mov byte[rbx],NULL
```

Comment: First thing spotted: `mov eax, DWORD [aLength]` when `aLength` is a byte. `rbx` points to...? The second loop is only 2 iterations. I already have answered your complementary question (bin -> dec), you can entirely reuse the concepts from there. if you want to simplify your code.

Comment: I see the code has been edited, but assuming `rax` has been zeroed, shouldn't it be `mov al,[aLength]`? The number you wish to convert is held in a single byte, defined by `aLength db 21`

Comment: That decimal number `21` is *automatically converted to binary* by the assembler. All you need to do is roll bits out of one end of `eax` (not `rax` as you only want 32 bits). No division is needed.

Comment: #1 : `mov eax,byte[aLength]` should be `mov al,byte[aLength]`. #2 : after the `lp2` loop, `mov rsi,tempString` should be `mov rbx,tempString`, because the `lp3` loop uses `rbx`. #3 : `mov rcx,2` before `lp3:` should be `mov rcx,32`.

Comment: Never use `div` to divide by 2.  Use [`shr` or `sar`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SAL:SAR:SHL:SHR.html).  The remainder is the bit shifted out into CF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets [debug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) your code together.

Debugging is something you <s>should</s> must do on your own, because writing code is just half of the story.
Honestly I thought this question would be downvoted, since it is actually the opposite it seems the People want it to be answered.

Now, you are asking a lot of similar questions<sup>4</sup> which shown a lack of debugging skills altogether.
So instead of telling the <s>easy to spot and debug</s> mistakes in your code, we will go through debugging, so maybe you'll learn something.

We will use GDB<sup>1</sup>. I started from your code<sup>2</sup>, made an assemblable version targeting  ELF64 and compiled the object file with gcc on Cygwin.

---

Lets first check that our values are loaded correctly.
Step through the first two instructions, the ones that set RAX up.

```
   ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
B+ │0x1004010e0 <WinMain>           mov    $0x0,%eax                           │
   │0x1004010e5 <WinMain+5>         mov    0xf25(%rip),%eax        # 0x10040201│
   │0x1004010eb <WinMain+11>        mov    $0x20,%ecx                          │
   │0x1004010f0 <lp2>               mov    $0x0,%edx                           │
  >│0x1004010f5 <lp2+5>             divq   0xf15(%rip)        # 0x100402011 <tw│
   │0x1004010fc <lp2+12>            push   %rdx                                │
   │0x1004010fd <lp2+13>            loop   0x1004010f0 <lp2>                   │
   │0x1004010ff <lp2+15>            movabs $0x100407000,%rsi                   │
   │0x100401109 <lp2+25>            mov    $0x2,%ecx                           │
   │0x10040110e <lp3>               pop    %rax                                │
   │0x10040110f <lp3+1>             add    $0x30,%al                           │
   │0x100401111 <lp3+3>             mov    %al,(%rbx)                          │
   │0x100401113 <lp3+5>             inc    %rbx                                │
   │0x100401116 <lp3+8>             loop   0x10040110e <lp3>                   │
   │0x100401118 <lp3+10>            movb   $0x0,(%rbx)                         │
   │0x10040111b <lp3+13>            retq                                       │
   └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
native Thread 5100.0x9e4 In: lp2                          L??   PC: 0x1004010f5
(gdb) si 4
0x00000001004010f5 in lp2 ()
(gdb) i r rax rcx rdx
rax            0x215    533
rcx            0x20     32
rdx            0x0      0
(gdb)
```

Shippity shop! What is happening here?
*RCX*, *RDX* look good, but *RAX* doesn't! Sure 533 is **a lot different** from 21.

After whole *ten minutes* of scraping out heads we finally figure out that the second instruction **is loading a DWORD from *aLength* which is a BYTE, so we are putting some rubbish into *RAX***.

So we correct that line<sup>3</sup>:

```
mov al, BYTE [aLength]
```

**We than again repeat the previous debugging step:**

```
(gdb) i r rax rcx rdx
rax            0x15     21
rcx            0x20     32
rdx            0x0      0
```

Good!
Now we execute the first iteration of the loop

---

```
   ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │0x1004010e5 <WinMain+5>         mov    0xf25(%rip),%al        # 0x100402010│
   │0x1004010eb <WinMain+11>        mov    $0x20,%ecx                          │
  >│0x1004010f0 <lp2>               mov    $0x0,%edx                           │
   │0x1004010f5 <lp2+5>             divq   0xf15(%rip)        # 0x100402011 <tw│
   │0x1004010fc <lp2+12>            push   %rdx                                │
   │0x1004010fd <lp2+13>            loop   0x1004010f0 <lp2>                   │
   │0x1004010ff <lp2+15>            movabs $0x100407000,%rsi                   │
   │0x100401109 <lp2+25>            mov    $0x2,%ecx                           │
   │0x10040110e <lp3>               pop    %rax                                │
   │0x10040110f <lp3+1>             add    $0x30,%al                           │
   │0x100401111 <lp3+3>             mov    %al,(%rbx)                          │
   │0x100401113 <lp3+5>             inc    %rbx                                │
   │0x100401116 <lp3+8>             loop   0x10040110e <lp3>                   │
   │0x100401118 <lp3+10>            movb   $0x0,(%rbx)                         │
   │0x10040111b <lp3+13>            retq                                       │
   └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
native Thread 4236.0x12e0 In: lp2                         L??   PC: 0x1004010f0
rdx            0x0      0
(gdb) si 3
0x00000001004010f0 in lp2 ()
(gdb) i r rax rcx rdx
rax            0xa      10
rcx            0x1f     31
rdx            0x1      1
(gdb)
```

Everything looks good: *RAX* has been halved, *RCX* is one less 32, *RDX* is the lsb of 21, which is one.
Lets just check that on the stack there effectively is this one.

```
A syntax error in expression, near `%rsp'.
(gdb) x/1dg $rsp
0xffffcb20:     1
```

Nice!

---

Since the loops seems ok, we can now **step outside of it and check the partial results**.

```
   ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │0x1004010dc <__gcc_deregister_frame+12> nop                                │
   │0x1004010dd <__gcc_deregister_frame+13> nop                                │
   │0x1004010de <__gcc_deregister_frame+14> nop                                │
   │0x1004010df <__gcc_deregister_frame+15> nop                                │
B+ │0x1004010e0 <WinMain>                   mov    $0x0,%eax                   │
   │0x1004010e5 <WinMain+5>                 mov    0xf25(%rip),%al        # 0x1│
   │0x1004010eb <WinMain+11>                mov    $0x20,%ecx                  │
   │0x1004010f0 <lp2>                       mov    $0x0,%edx                   │
   │0x1004010f5 <lp2+5>                     divq   0xf15(%rip)        # 0x10040│
   │0x1004010fc <lp2+12>                    push   %rdx                        │
   │0x1004010fd <lp2+13>                    loop   0x1004010f0 <lp2>           │
  >│0x1004010ff <lp2+15>                    movabs $0x100407000,%rsi           │
   │0x100401109 <lp2+25>                    mov    $0x2,%ecx                   │
   │0x10040110e <lp3>                       pop    %rax                        │
   │0x10040110f <lp3+1>                     add    $0x30,%al                   │
   └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
native Thread 4236.0x12e0 In: lp2                         L??   PC: 0x1004010ff
(gdb) p/u *(unsigned long long (*)[32])$rsp
$3 = {0 <repeats 27 times>, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}
(gdb)
```

The register are surely ok, so we only check the pushed values.
As GDB tells us, the number 21 has been correctly converted into 0..010101.

---

We now again debug the **first iteration** of the next loop:

```
   ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  >│0x10040110e <lp3>               pop    %rax                                │
   │0x10040110f <lp3+1>             add    $0x30,%al                           │
   │0x100401111 <lp3+3>             mov    %al,(%rbx)                          │
   │0x100401113 <lp3+5>             inc    %rbx                                │
   │0x100401116 <lp3+8>             loop   0x10040110e <lp3>                   │
   │0x100401118 <lp3+10>            movb   $0x0,(%rbx)                         │
   │0x10040111b <lp3+13>            retq                                       │
   │0x10040111c <lp3+14>            nopl   0x0(%rax)                           │
   │0x100401120 <__cxa_atexit>      jmpq   *0x6fbe(%rip)        # 0x1004080e4 <│
   │0x100401126 <__cxa_atexit+6>    nop                                        │
   │0x100401127 <__cxa_atexit+7>    nop                                        │
   │0x100401128 <__cxa_atexit+8>    nop                                        │
   │0x100401129 <__cxa_atexit+9>    nop                                        │
   │0x10040112a <__cxa_atexit+10>   nop                                        │
   │0x10040112b <__cxa_atexit+11>   nop                                        │
   └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
native Thread 4236.0x12e0 In: lp3                         L??   PC: 0x10040110e
0x0000000100401116 in lp3 ()
(gdb) si
0x000000010040110e in lp3 ()
(gdb) i r rsi rax rbx rcx
rsi            0x100407000      4299190272
rax            0x30     48
rbx            0x285541 2643265
rcx            0x1      1
(gdb)
```

Oh snap!
*RSI* has **not** been incremented! Also *RCX* is 1 after just one iteration.  *RAX* is fine though.

After another whole *ten minutes* of frustrating thinking we realize that we are using *EBX* in the loop, not *RSI* and we set *RCX* to 2 not 32!

We fix those:

```
mov rbx, tempString
mov rcx, 32
```

---

Finally we try running the program until the end.
Once done, we examine the string written:

```
(gdb) x/4xg 0x100407000
0x100407000 <tempString>:       0x3030303030303030      0x3030303030303030
0x100407010 <tempString+16>:    0x3030303030303030      0x3130313031303030
```

Which, taking endianess into account is

```
30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   30 30 30 31 30 32 30 31
```

confirming the correctness of the program.

---

[Here again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37831032/5801661), you program can be simplified using the same trick of using the *CF*:

```
 movzx ebx, BYTE [REL aLength]      ;EBX = Byte to convert
 mov rcx, 32                        ;RCX = Bits left to convert
 mov rdi, tempString                ;RDI = Pointer to output string

 xor eax, eax
 mov al, '0'                        ;RAX = Aux value

_convert:

 shr eax, 1                         ;Get rid of RAX bit 0

 shl ebx, 1                         ;Set CF to the current msb of EBX
 rcl eax, 1                         ;Shift into RAX the CF

 stosb                              ;Store ASCII digit

 sub rcx, 1                         ;Repeat
ja _convert

 mov BYTE [rdi], cl         ;Write NULL TERM
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Because beggars can't be choosers. [This cheatsheet](http://darkdust.net/files/GDB%20Cheat%20Sheet.pdf) will be useful.
<sup>2</sup> The original one, not the fishy patched one.
<sup>3</sup> Implementing the possible ugliest way to load a byte into *RAX*.
<sup>4</sup> As I explained in a comment, one of you question is essentially the complementary of this one and could be reused quite straightforwardly.

Comment: I like your "ten minutes of scraping out heads" and "another whole ten minutes of frustrating thinking". Personally I don't think using a debugger on such a trivial piece of code simplifies matters for the novice. To the trained eye, everything that's wrong with the OP's code was just screaming! Whatever happened to the ancient art of just scrutinating the code?

Comment: @SepRoland That's true. If you look at the comments you'll see that everybody already spotted the mistakes indeed. But since the OP was flooding the sites with questions like this (essentially, debug this code for me) I thought that a guided debugging session would help :)